# Play a custom sound after some time when a key pressed on android custom keyboard

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to play a sound (custom, not system default) after some seconds when a key is pressed. I got a countdown timer running on the key. So want to play a sound `onFinish` function.
my code for that key is:

```
if(isCountDownRunning)
  return;
isCountDownRunning = true;
new CountDownTimer(14000, 1000) {

  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    keyboard.getKeys().get(0).label = millisUntilFinished / (1000) + "";
    kv.invalidateKey(0);
  }

  public void onFinish() {
    isCountDownRunning = false;
    keyboard.getKeys().get(0).label ="ADV";
    kv.invalidateKey(0);
  }
}.start();
break;
```

Comment: `final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);` create mp like this and use mp.start() where you want

Comment: where do I add that custom sound in my project. and how to call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the custom sound in a folder `res/raw/` . Then use MediaPlayer to play sound like,

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, rid);//rid -->R.raw.customsound 
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
    }
});
```

> want to play a sound onFinish function

In your onFinish function, add this line

```
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: do I need to import anything?

Comment: unknown variable `context`, unknown method `stop();`

Comment: context is your activity context. and I edited my answer

Comment: still `stop();` is unknown method 

Comment: did you try mediaPlayer.stop();

Comment: that is `mMediaPlayer.stop();`

Comment: The sound playing only once. Second onwards time it doesn't plays

Comment: for every keypress call start() method

Comment: i did. but not helps.

Comment: `/*mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
     mp.stop();
    }
   });` just removed this much part. Now it working cool.